# How import grafana dashboard for Istio?

Tags: kubernetes, observable, grafana, istio

I use grafana helm chart and configmap for importing dashboards, but when I try to load the official Istio dashboard, I get:

```
logger=provisioning.dashboard type=file name=sidecarProvider t=2023-04-13T12:28:39.524808833Z level=error msg="failed to load dashboard from " file=/tmp/dashboards/Istio/istio-performance-dashboard.json error="Dashboard title cannot be empty"
```

How can I fix it? I can fix the `title` field and save the work version in the Helm chart, but it's bad because I'll need to change the original dashboards every time.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

I see you are trying to import `Istio Performance Dashboard` using the grafana helm chart (as you mentioned), which would be [this](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/grafana)

As an alternative to importing a dashboard(s) in grafana via the json file & configmap, you could also import the dashboard using the dashboard id from `grafana.com`. The configuration needs to go into the values.yaml when using that helm chart.

Specifically [here](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/grafana-6.52.9/charts/grafana/values.yaml#L636) to enable/configure dashboardProviders and [here](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/grafana-6.52.9/charts/grafana/values.yaml#L655) to provision the dashboard using dashboard id from the grafana website.

In your case, the values should look like this:

```
dashboardProviders:
  dashboardproviders.yaml:
   apiVersion: 1
   providers:
   - name: 'default'
     orgId: 1
     folder: 'default'
     type: file
     disableDeletion: true
     editable: true
     options:
       path: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/standard

dashboards:
  default:
    Istio Perf:
      gnetId: 11829
      revision: 162
      datasource: yourdatasource
```

Shows up in grafana:

[image]

No metrics ofcourse as I don't have a data source.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In summary I use dashboard from github:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: istio-extension-dashboard
  labels:
    grafana_dashboard: "true"
  annotations:
    grafana_dashboard_folder: Istio
data:
  istio-extension-dashboard.json.url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/master/manifests/addons/dashboards/istio-extension-dashboard.json"
```

for example: [link](https://github.com/shortlink-org/shortlink/blob/f34285b511eb5de046f0aa95d71cec13a8985d7b/ops/Helm/addons/gateway/istio-gateway/templates/grafana/istio-extension-dashboard.yaml)

for some reason there is a dashboard on the githab itself with the correct `title` field - this solved the problem with the empty field